# Nothing happening in CRON

Tags: amazon-ec2, fedora, cron

I put in a command for crontab but nothing seems to be happening.

**#vi /etc/crontab**

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
# For details see man 4 crontabs
# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
10 * * * * cd /var/www/html/mt; ./tools/run-periodic-tasks ~
```

And crond is running..

> `# service crond status`
>
> `# crond (pid  7070) is running...`

It suppose to rebuild a html from Movable Type every 10min.  I am on Amazon EC2 Linux 64bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the system wide /etc/crontab you must also specificy which user to run as. That would be a column in itself, going after dow, but before the command being run.

Also, as Ignacio just mentioned, for it to be run every 10 minutes, you want to use */10.

Hence

```
*/10  *  *  *  *   USER   cd /var/www/html/mt; ./tools/run-periodic-tasks ~
```

Answer (score 1):

Your specification says "10 minutes after the hour". Try `*/10` instead.